# Got `function () { [native code] }` value in result of HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, nan

### I'm getting **function () { [native code] }** value in HTML result.

> `function getWarning(type)` get the warning by type from warnings array.
>   
>   `function getCaches()` get all cached warning from caches array.
>   `function cacheWarning(type)` add cached warning if not in caches
>   array.

**JavaScript :**

```
    var warnings=['- Le nom très petite !','- Cette prénom très petite ! !',"- Votre age invalide, le moin de l'age est 18 !","- Le numéro de téléphone incorrect !",'- Email invalide !',"- Le mot de pass doit de contient les caractéres et les nombres !",'- Le mot de pass sans confirmer !'];
    var caches=new Array("");
    var i=0;
    function getWarning(type){
         i=0;
         for(i in warnings){
               if(warnings[i].includes(type)){return warnings[i];}
         }
    }
    function getCaches(){
          let allCaches="";
          i=0;
          for(i in caches){
             allCaches+=caches[i]+"<br/>";
          }
          return allCaches;
    }
    function cacheWarning(type){
        i=0;
        for(i in caches){
        if(caches[i]==getWarning(type)){
            return -1;
            }
        }
        caches[caches.length]=getWarning(type);
     }

if(document.getElementsByName("prenom")[0].value.length<=2){if(cacheWarning("prénom")!=-1){$("#content").html(getCaches())}}
```

**Debugage result:**
[image: This is screenshot explain that variable 'i' is NaN, I got it after inspected elements from navigator]

**HTML result:**
[image: This is screenshot from navigator explain HTML's result]

Comment: two of those functions could return `undefined` - can't see any reason you'd get `NaN` anywhere - also, no need to initialise `i=0` in those functions, personally I'd use `for (let i in caches` ... also I'd use `caches[caches.length-1]=getWarning(type);` simply replaces the last value in caches, so caches will never be more than one element

Comment: I was want to add values in caches array by `caches[caches.length-1]=getWarning(type);` but it was replace them and got **NuN**. I'm change it now to be  `caches[caches.length]=getWarning(type);`, thank you. But, **HTML result** is still **function () { [native code]}**.

Comment: Just before `$("#content").html(getCaches())` add the line `console.log(caches)` - what does that look like?

Comment: After added `consol.lig(caches)`. I got this `CacheStorage {undefined: "- Cette prénom très petite ! !"}
undefined: "- Le mot de pass sans confirmer !"`

Comment: where does the string `CacheStorage` come from - can't see that anywhere in your code

Comment: ahhh, `caches` seems to be some built-in browser thing ... rename the `caches` var everywhere in your code to something else

Comment: You solve it ! thank you sooo much.